# How to export all components in index.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a trivial problem. Having this file structure, I'd like to expose all components (in index.js) so they are reachable in App.js, like that: `import { Header, Menu } from "../components";`. But I'm getting error that neither `Home` nor `Menu` are in the components. Here is the structure:

```
src/
  index.js
  app/
    App.js
    createStore.js
    reducers.js
  components/
    index.js  <--------------- In here, I'd like to export all components
    button/
      Button.js
      Button.styles.js
    header/
      Header.js
      Header.styles.js
  modules/ 
    foo/
    bar/
```

This is Header:

```
import React from "react";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import useStyles from "./Header.styles";

const Header = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h5">LineupFarm</Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

This is components/index.js

```
import Header from "../components/Header/Header";
import Menu from "../components/Menu/Menu";

export default {
  Header,
  Menu,
};
```

... and this is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider, CssBaseline, Toolbar } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Header, Menu } from "../components"; // <------------ Getting error: "Menu not found in '../components'" Why?

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Header />
        <Menu />
        <main className={classes.content}>
        </main>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why am I getting error "Menu not found in '../components'"? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note you have a trailing comma after `Menu` in the export

Comment: it seems like you don't have a Menu.js in your ```components``` folder

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your index.js you can just directly do

```
export {default as Header} from "../components/Header/Header";
export {default as Menu} from "../components/Menu/Menu";
```

In this way we're importing the default export from the module of your choice and exporting it as a namespaced module.

Now you can import components as

```
import {Header, Menu} from "../components";
```

Comment: Hmm.. Shouldn't `export {default as Header} from "../components/Header/Header";` be the same as `export Header from "../components/Header/Header";`?

Comment: No `export Header from "../components/Header/Header"` won't work. Since in an external file you can't directly delegate default export.

Answer (score 3):

Your original syntax is exposing an object outside. If you want to use it in `App.js`, you may take the following code as reference

```
//App.js
import Component from "../components";

return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component.Header />
        <Component.Menu />
        <main className={classes.content}>
        </main>
      </div>
  );

//
```

From my experience, the following code may work if you wanna use `import {Header, Button} from "../components"`

```
// in index.js
export {default as Button} from "../components/Button/Button"
export {default as Header} from "../components/Header/Header"

//in App.js
import {Button, Header} from "../components"
```

Answer (score 2):

In your index.js, you have

```js
export default {
  Header,
  Menu,
};
```

which is exporting a default object with the properties `Header` and `Menu`, rather exporting individual named properties.

With your current setup you could do the following in App.js:

```js
// the name you use here is up to you, because it is a default export
import components from "../components";
const Header = components.Header;
...
<Header>
```

But more likely what you want is to remove the `default` from the export in index.js, so you can import your individual components by name.

You can read more about default vs. named exports [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to be able to import like this: `import { Header, Menu } from "../components";` in `App.js`. How can I `implement components/index.js` to achive that?

Comment: If you remove `default` from your export in components/index.js, you should be able to use that import syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively export components like this:

Your `index.js`:

```
export Menu from "../components/Menu/Menu"
export Header from '../components/Header/Header"
```

Then you can access all your components by importing it like this:

```
import * as Components from "../components"
```

Alternatively, you can simply write this:

```
import { Menu, Header} from "../components'
```

it is a babel plugin called `` @babel/plugin-proposal`export-default-from ``. You may refer to this [link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-export-default-from.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the default it works perfectly well

```js
import Header from "../components/Header/Header";
import Menu from "../components/Menu/Menu";

export {
  Header,
  Menu,
};
```